# How to find $a \times b = 72$ and $a + b = -17$ algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to understand how to find  $a \times b = 72$ and $a + b = -17$. Or I am fine with any other example, even general form $a \times b = c$ and $a + b = d$, how to find $a$ and $b$.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: can you solve $x^2 - d x + c = 0$? Or just try integer divisors of `72` until you find two who add up to `-17`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $a+b=-17\implies a=-17-b$. So put it back in the second equation

$(-17-b)b=72\implies b^2+17b+72=0$ which is a quadratic equation in $b$. Solving it you will get $b=-9$ or $b=-8$ thus giving $a=-8$ or $a=-9$.

Answer (score 8):

**If** the equations hold, then $(a+b)^2=289$, and therefore 
$$(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab=289-288=1.$$
Thus $a-b=\pm 1$ and $a+b=-17$.

Solving the system of linear equations, we obtain $a=-8$, $b=-9$ or $a=-9$, $b=-8$. It is easy to verify that both of these satisfy the given equations.

The same strategy will work in general.